# Seq seq type as a member parameter in F#

Tags: f#, sequences, static-members

why does not this code work?

```
type Test() =
  static member func (a: seq<'a seq>) = 5.

let a = [[4.]]
Test.func(a)
```

It gives following error:

```
The type 'float list list' is not compatible with the type 'seq<seq<'a>>'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your code to

```
type Test() = 
  static member func (a: seq<#seq<'a>>) = 5. 

let a = [[4.]] 
Test.func(a)
```

The trick is in the type of a. You need to explicitly allow the outer seq to hold instances of seq<'a> **and** subtypes of seq<'a>. Using the # symbol enables this.

Answer (score 6):

The error message describes the problem -- in F#, `list<list<'a>>` isn't compatible with `seq<seq<'a>>`.

The `upcast` function helps get around this, by making `a` into a `list<seq<float>>`, which is then compatible with `seq<seq<float>>`:

```
let a = [upcast [4.]]
Test.func(a)
```

**Edit:** You can make `func` more flexible in the types it accepts. The original accepts only sequences of `seq<'a>`. Even though `list<'a>` implements `seq<'a>`, the types aren't identical, and the compiler gives you an error.

However, you can modify `func` to accept sequences of any type, as long as that type implements `seq<'a>`, by writing the inner type as `#seq`:

```
type Test() =
  static member func (a: seq<#seq<'a>>) = 5.

let a = [[4.]]
Test.func(a) // works
```

Comment: And why is it so? If you write "let func (a: seq<'a seq>) = 5." then it works without any upcasting.

Comment: My mistake. You are right. Do you have any explanation why for 'let func (a : float seq) = 5.' we do not have to do upcasting and for seq seq we have to do that?

Comment: `seq<'a>` and `seq<'b>` are fundamentally different types in F#, even if you (as the programmer) know that any `'b` and be converted to `'a`. You have to do the conversion in the code by hand; in this case, with `upcast`. But see my edited answer...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Now I understand it a little more.